# Configuring LACP between OpenIndiana (Solaris) and a Cisco C3560

Tags: solaris, opensolaris, openindiana, lacp

I am running OpenIndiana (oi_151a8) and have two NICs aggregated using LACP connected to a Cisco WS-C3560G-48TS. Both the server and the switch show the aggregate link as up. But while link layer traffic is visible ('snoop' shows ARP requests etc), I can not pass any IP traffic (ping, ssh all fail). The really strange thing is that the aggregate link can obtain a DHCP address, which provides the correct gateway, name servers etc. My initial thoughts were that there was a problem with the VLAN configuration, but the switch is running everything on VLAN1. I also tried explicitly adding this on both ends, but without success (OI won't let me configure a VLAN with the native VLAN). Any ideas?

**CONFIGURATION ON THE SERVER**

```
svcadm disable network/physical:nwam
svcadm enable network/physical:default
dladm create-aggr -l e1000g0 -l e1000g1 aggr1
ipadm create-addr -T DHCP aggr1/v4
dladm modify-aggr -L active -T long aggr1
```

**VERIFICATION ON THE SERVER** 
(had to OCR this, so some text is mangled)

```
admin@arc01:~# dladm show-link
LINK CLASS MTU STATE BRIDGE OVER
e1000g0 phys 1500 up -- --
e1000g1 phys 1500 up -- --
aggr1 aggr 1500 up —— e1000g0 e1000g1

admin@arc01:~# dladm show-phys
LINK MEDIA STATE SPEED DUPLEX DEVICE
e1000g0 Ethernet up 1000 full e1000g0
e1000g1 Ethernet up 1000 full e1000g1

admin@arc01:~# dladm show—ether
LINE PTYPE STATE AUTO SPEED-DUPLEX PAUSE
e1000g0 current up yes 1G—f bi
e1000g1 current up yes 1G-f bi

admin@arc01:~# dladm show-aggr
LINK POLICY ADDRPOLICY LACPACTIVITY LACPTIMER FLAGS
aggr1 L4 auto active long -----

admin@arc01:~# ifconfig aggr1
aggr1: Flags=1004843{UP,BROADCAST.RUNNING.MULTICAST,DHCP.IPv4} mtu 1500 index 3
inet 192.168.0.200 netmask ffffff00 broadcast 192.168.0.255
ether 68:5:ca:11:19:a6

Routing table shows the following: netstat -r
default          192.168.0.1  UG   2  3   aggr1
arc01           arc01            UH  2   48 lo0
192.168.0.0 192.168.0.200 U    3  1   aggr1
```

**CONFIGURATION ON THE SWITCH**

```
interface Port-channel10
 description ARC01_LACP
interface GigabitEthernet0/41
 description ARC01_LACP
 channel-group 10 mode active
interface GigabitEthernet0/42
 description ARC01_LACP
 channel-group 10 mode active
```

**VERIFICATION ON THE SWITCH**

```
SW01#show interfaces port-channel 10
Port-channel10 is up, line protocol is up (connected) 
  Hardware is EtherChannel, address is 001f.6d21.14a9 (bia 001f.6d21.14a9)
  Description: ARC01_LACP
  MTU 1500 bytes, BW 2000000 Kbit, DLY 10 usec, 
     reliability 255/255, txload 1/255, rxload 1/255
  Encapsulation ARPA, loopback not set
  Keepalive set (10 sec)
  Full-duplex, 1000Mb/s, link type is auto, media type is unknown
  input flow-control is off, output flow-control is unsupported 
  Members in this channel: Gi0/41 Gi0/42 
  ARP type: ARPA, ARP Timeout 04:00:00
  Last input never, output 00:00:01, output hang never
  Last clearing of "show interface" counters never
  Input queue: 0/75/0/0 (size/max/drops/flushes); Total output drops: 0
  Queueing strategy: fifo
  Output queue: 0/40 (size/max)
  5 minute input rate 0 bits/sec, 0 packets/sec
  5 minute output rate 2000 bits/sec, 3 packets/sec
     1766 packets input, 204558 bytes, 0 no buffer
     Received 1750 broadcasts (1417 multicasts)
     0 runts, 0 giants, 0 throttles
     0 input errors, 0 CRC, 0 frame, 0 overrun, 0 ignored
     0 watchdog, 1417 multicast, 0 pause input
     0 input packets with dribble condition detected
     197210 packets output, 29618326 bytes, 0 underruns
     0 output errors, 0 collisions, 1 interface resets
     0 babbles, 0 late collision, 0 deferred
     0 lost carrier, 0 no carrier, 0 PAUSE output
     0 output buffer failures, 0 output buffers swapped out
```

Comment: I think I need to start again from scratch: upon reboot I noticed a collection of errors along the lines of:  svc:/network/physical:default: Method “/lib/svc/method/net-physical” failed with exit status 96.
network/physical:default misconfigured: transitioned to maintenance (see ‘svcs -xv’ for details)